# Send 2 identical Graphql queries in one call but with different variables

Tags: reactjs, angular, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a search query which takes an variable and searches based on that.

On my home page I'd like to send this query 3 times with 3 different variables.

But if I do as above I can't get the results.

Here is the query:

```
const TOP_TEACHER_QUERY= gql`
    query topTeachers {
        searchBasicTeachersByRating(rating: 3) {
            id
            name
            title
        }
        searchBasicTeachersByRating(rating: 4) {
            id
            name
            title
            isNew
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the function

```
allQueries() {
    return this.apollo
        .watchQuery<any>({
            query: TOP_TEACHER_QUERY,
        })
        .valueChanges;
}
```

**NOTE :**

I have tried adding an interface and define the desired response data, but it has no effect

```
interface Response {
    searchBasicTeachersByRatingMedium: Student[];
    searchBasicTeachersByRatingHigh: Student[];
}

allQueries() {
    return this.apollo
        .watchQuery<any>({
            query: TOP_TEACHER_QUERY,
        })
        .valueChanges;
}
```

*THE DATA IS ONLY CONTAINING A LIST NAMED AFTER THE QUERY (searchBasicTeachersByRating)*

I have tried the following query in graphql playground and it returns 2 arrays
but in Angular I can only get one

As a work around I created new queries at back-end, or sent 2 different queries.

But I want a solution for this approach.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a selection set includes the same field multiple times, you need to utilize aliases for the duplicate fields:

```
searchBasicTeachersByRatingMedium: searchBasicTeachersByRating(rating: 3) {
  id
  name
  title
}
searchBasicTeachersByRatingHigh: searchBasicTeachersByRating(rating: 4) {
  id
  name
  title
  isNew
}
```

After the request completes, each field will be available as a property on `data` under the provided alias. In the example above, we aliased both fields, but you could omit the alias from one of them.